# Default application for opening binary files WITHOUT extension

Tags: default-programs, sublime-text, binary

I want to set Sublime Text Editor as the default app for opening binary files without extension (e.g. log files that are stored without extension).

Right-clicking on the file and going to properties does not work, as the "Open With" tab does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

**Changing Default Applications For Other File Types** 
An alternative way to choose a default application is to use the "Files" file manager.
Click on the icon that looks like a filing cabinet and navigate through the folder structure until you find a file that you wish to change the default application for. For instance navigate to the music folder and find an MP3 file.
Right click on the file, select "open with" and then either choose one of the applications listed or choose "other application".

A new window will appear called "Recommended Applications".
You can choose one of the recommended applications listed but you could have done that from the "open with" menu.
If you click the "View All Applications" button a list of every application will be shown. The chances are that none of these are relevant to the file type you are using otherwise it would be listed as a recommended application.
A better button to use is the "Find New Applications" button. Clicking this button brings up the Gnome Package Manager with a list of relevant applications for that file type.
Look through the list and click install next to the program you wish to install.
You will need to close the Gnome Package Manager after the application has installed.
You will notice that the recommended applications now contains your new program. You can click it to make it the default.

Source: https://www.lifewire.com/change-default-programs-associated-file-type-ubuntu-2205574

Comment: This does not make the app the default - it only opens it.